# Android - does setting bitmap request Options.inJustDecodeBounds to true reduce request time?

Tags: android, url, bitmap, inputstream, bitmapfactory

I am coding an app where I am going to acquire bitmaps from URLs using inputstreams. Before they have been loaded, however, I require a placeholder. My current plan is to first get the bounds of the bitmap (using Options and inJustDecodeBounds) and use this to set the placeholder aspect ratio and size.

However, if it takes the same amount of time to do this kind of request as it takes to simply request the actual bitmap, then I may as well simply request the actual bitmap.

So does setting inJustDecodeBounds to true in an instance of BitmapFactory.Options reduce the time taken for the request?

Answer (score 0):

The using of inJustDecodeBounds reduce the required amount of memory to get only the bitmap information.
It's not a question about speed.

Comment: So it doesn't make the request faster?

Comment: No, but you should use it if you want do some calculations that require the bitmap size. See http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html: Setting the inJustDecodeBounds property to true while decoding avoids memory allocation, returning null for the bitmap object but setting outWidth, outHeight and outMimeType. This technique allows you to read the dimensions and type of the image data prior to construction (and memory allocation) of the bitmap.

Comment: however, if you are repeating this calculation, say for a detail view that is using the same resources as the overview, you may want to hold onto some of the information you get after the first, non-malloc calculation =]

Useful thread!